# How to check if a node is already exist

Tags: graph-algorithm, graphstream

I want to check if the node is already exist in the graph before adding a new node.

I tried to do it using a foreach loop.But it didnt work.

```
boolean returnVal = false;
         for (Node node : displayGraph) {
             if (node.getId().equals(n.getId())){
                 returnVal = true;
             }
             else{
                 returnVal =false;
             }
         }
```

I want to retrieve true if the node is already exist on the graph

Comment: You could store all node Ids in a hashset and then check the hashset prior to adding a new node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check what `Graph.getNode(String)` returns. If no node with that string id exist, then `null` is returned:

```java
boolean returnVal = displayGraph.getNode(n.getId()) == null ? false : true;
```